# Wordpress while loop - group 15 elements in one div

Tags: wordpress, loops

To display a bunch of logos inside my wordpress template i need to group the output of some logos, stored in an advanced custom fields, into 15 elements inside a div.

My acutall loop:

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

     <!-- logo -->
     <div class="logo">
         <img src="logo.jpg"/>
      </div>    
     <!-- end logo -->

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The output should look loke

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>        
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>        
</div>

<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>        
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"</div>        
</div>
```

And so on...

Comment: Are the logos stored in an array on those custom fields or are they all separate?

Answer (score 0):

try plese.

```
<?php if ($wp_query->current_post < 15) { ?>
</div>
<div class="logo-wrapper">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This creates a wrapper for the first 15 posts. Thats not actually what i need. I need to group the elements inside the query into blocks of 15 logos.